# how to check counter value is incremented or not in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme

I make a simple demo of counter where I have two button `increment` and `decrement`.demo is working fine . but now I want to test my component. my test case fail when I click on `increment button` .I am using `enzyme` and `jest`.

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-tharp-ty92o?file=/src/App.test.js

**test case fail**

```
test("clicking button increments counter display", () => {
  const counter = 7;
  const wrapper = setup(null, { counter });

  // find button and click
  const button = findByTestAttr(wrapper, "increment-button");
  button.simulate("click");

  // find display and test value
  const counterDisplay = findByTestAttr(wrapper, "counter-display");
  expect(counterDisplay.text()).toContain(counter + 1);
});
```

getting error

**ShallowWrapper::setState() can only be called on class components**

[image]

Comment: `if (state) wrapper.setState(state)` What is this doing?

Comment: i think I am using `function component` .it is method of `class component`

Comment: Perhaps you are trying to test the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't manipulate the internal state of a functional component, especially not with class-based `this.setState`.

`0` is the initial default state of the counter, so you should simply test that clicking the "+" button updates the UI to `1`.

```
const setup = (props = {}, state = null) => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<App {...props} />);
  // if (state) wrapper.setState(state); // <-- can't do this!!
  return wrapper;
};

...

test("clicking button increments counter display", () => {
  const wrapper = setup(); // initial count is 0

  // find button and click
  const button = findByTestAttr(wrapper, "increment-button");
  button.simulate("click");

  // find display and test value
  const counterDisplay = findByTestAttr(wrapper, "counter-display");
  expect(counterDisplay.text()).toContain(1); // new count is 1
});
```

## Update to provide initial props

Expose out some initial value prop to be passed to the hook

```
export default function App({ initialCount }) {
  const { state, increment, decrement } = useCounter(initialCount);
  return (
    <div className="App" data-test="component-app">
      <h1 data-test="counter-display">{state}</h1>
      <button data-test="increment-button" onClick={increment}>
        +
      </button>
      <button data-test="decrement-button" onClick={decrement}>
        -
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Update hook to pass initial value to state (***Use functional state updates correctly!!***)

```
export default (initialCount) => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(initialCount);

  const increment = () => {
    setState(preState => preState + 1);
  };

  const decrement = () => {
    setState(preState => preState - 1);
  };

  return {
    state,
    increment,
    decrement
  };
};
```

And update the test suite

```
const setup = (props = {}) => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<App {...props} />);
  return wrapper;
};

...

test("clicking button increments counter display", () => {
  const initialCount = 10;
  const wrapper = setup({ initialCount });

  // find button and click
  const button = findByTestAttr(wrapper, "increment-button");
  button.simulate("click");

  // find display and test value
  const counterDisplay = findByTestAttr(wrapper, "counter-display");
  expect(counterDisplay.text()).toContain(initialCount + 1);
});
```

[image: Edit cocky-shtern-27smh]

Suggestion: Consider switching over to React Testing Library, it's actually more intuitive and tests a component the way a user would interact with it instead of meddling with the internal implementation details, essentially more like how your last test works.

Comment: see can I give initial value see https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-tharp-ty92o?file=/src/App.test.js

Comment: I little change in `useCounter`  give some initial value (from where it start incremement) and decrement

Comment: @user944513 You need to expose out the prop in `App`, like `function App({ initialCount}) {...` and pass that to `useCounter`, like `const {...} = useCounter(initialCount);`. I can update my answer and sandbox if this is what you're really trying to go for.

Comment: can we mock `useCounter` ?

Comment: thanks for `suggestion` . can we use both `React Testing Library` and enzyme in same project ?

Comment: @user944513 Answer updated, sandbox updated, and yes, you sure can.

Comment: @user944513 FYI, just updated the custom hook to use a more correct functional state update, pre-incrementing/decrementing actually mutates current state.